# First row of data has become a column in Pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

The first row in pandas data table has turned into a column. I've tried various renaming methods and restructuring and it hasn't been working. Something really trivial, but unfortunately I need some help.

[image]

The line "0" is supposed to come down as the first data row "Bachelor". Could someone please point me to the proper way of getting this done?

Comment: How was created DataFrame?

Answer (score 9):

I think there is problem your csv have no header, so is possible create default range columns names:

```
df_degree = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
```

Or is possible define custom columns names:

```
df_degree = pd.read_csv(file, names=['col1','col2'])
```